# How to build pure css carousel in transform

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transforms

Looking for pure css carousel, it has been started a bit but still not sure whether possible or not. The aim with the snippet is to move images left to right and make `transform: rotateY(0.25turn)` when reach left for hiding with help of `backface-visibility: hidden;` ;-) after that move the image to left then `transform: rotateY(0.25turn)`. Hope the question is clear

[image: Is it possible to build css carousel with cuy]

**Is it possible to build css carousel with current snippet ?**

```css
@keyframes turn {
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(5deg) rotateY(0.5turn);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(1turn);
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

body .container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 700px;
}

body .container .carousel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 140px;
  height: 97px;
  margin-left: -70px;
  margin-top: -48.5px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(0);
  animation: turn 20s infinite linear;
}

body .container .carousel .slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 97px;
  user-select: none;
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(36deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(72deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(108deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(144deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotateY(216deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotateY(252deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotateY(288deg) translateZ(280px);
}

body .container .carousel .slide:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotateY(324deg) translateZ(280px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=01" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=02" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=03" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=04" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=05" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=06" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=07" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=08" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=09" alt="" class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=10" alt="" class="slide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Its not clear in your question.

Comment: @FluffyKitten the images need to move slowly right to left. The solution I found `transform: rotateY(0.25turn)` to hide then start from the beginning again. Hope you got the point :-)

Comment: Please update your question with a description of what you are trying to do, not everyone will see it in the comments. It would also help if you include what you have already tried to do to make this change.

Comment: @FluffyKitten just update, Hope it is question is clear now

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background-color: #eefbf8;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle, hsla(0,0%,100%,.1), hsla(0,0%,0%,.75)),
                      linear-gradient(left, transparent 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.01) 50%);
    background-position: 50% 75%, 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-size: 150% 150%, 3em 3em;
    font-size: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
  /**********/
 /* Slider */
/**********/

.slider {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                0 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.75),
                0 -1px 1px 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    height: 18.75em;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -9.875em -13em;
    padding: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 25em;
}

/* Frame */

.slider:before {
    background-color: #22130c;
    bottom: -2.5em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.2),
                inset 0 -2px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.4),
                0 5px 50px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25),
                0 20px 20px -15px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                0 30px 20px -15px hsla(0,0%,0%,.15),
                0 40px 20px -15px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    content: '';
    left: -2.5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -2.5em;
    top: -2.5em;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* Mat */

.slider:after {
    background-color: #fff5e5;
    bottom: -1.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.2),
                0 -1px 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.4),
                inset 0 2px 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                inset 0 4px 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.2),
                inset 0 6px 3px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
    content: '';
    left: -1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -1.5em;
    top: -1.5em;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* Slides */

.slider li {
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 2px hsla(0,0%,0%,.03);
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
}
.slider input {
    display: none;
}

/* Navigation */

.slider label {
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, hsla(0,0%,0%,.25));
    border: .2em solid transparent;
    bottom: .5em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: .5em;
    left: 24em;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .25s;
    width: .5em;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}
.slider label:after {
    border-radius: 100%;
    bottom: -.2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .2em #111,
                inset 0 2px 2px #000,
                0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.25);
    content: '';
    left: -.2em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -.2em;
    top: -.2em;
}
.slider:hover label {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.slider input:checked + label {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.slider:hover li:nth-child(1) label {
    left: .5em;
}
.slider:hover li:nth-child(2) label {
    left: 2em;
}
.slider:hover li:nth-child(3) label {
    left: 3.5em;
}
.slider:hover li:nth-child(4) label {
    left: 5em;
}

/* Images */

.slider img {
    height: 18.75em;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .25s;
    width: 25em;
    vertical-align: top;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slider li input:checked ~ img {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
​
```

```html
<ul class="slider">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="slide" checked>
        <label for="slide1"></label>
        <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/322/screenshots/872485/coldchase.jpg" alt="Panel 1">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="slide">
        <label for="slide2"></label>
       <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/322/screenshots/980517/icehut_sm.jpg" alt="Panel 2">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="slide">
        <label for="slide3"></label>
        <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/322/screenshots/943660/hq_sm.jpg" alt="Panel 3">
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://cssslider.com/">
        <input type="radio" id="slide4" name="slide">
        <label for="slide4"></label>
        <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/322/screenshots/599584/home.jpg" alt="Panel 4"></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Images from Craig Henry's Dribbble profile: http://dribbble.com/craighenry -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually I am looking for solution for moving multiple images without clicking anywhere. something like this https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/bojLQN

Comment: Ohhh you need like marquee (Y)

Comment: exactly, the images need to move slowly right to left. The solution I found transform: rotateY(0.25turn) to hide then start from the beginning again